# Не работает условие php mysql pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не работает данное условие?

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
    $db   = '';
    $user = '';
    $pass = '';
    $charset = 'utf8';
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM task WHERE id_t = ".$_GET['id']."");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
if ($row['process_t'] == $_POST['process_t']) {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
    $s1="UPDATE task SET name_t='".$_POST['name_t']."', desc_t='".$_POST['desc_t']."', process_t='".$_POST['process_t']."', status_t='".$_POST['status_t']."', client_t='".$_POST['user_id']."'  WHERE id_t='".$_POST['id']."'";
}
else {
    $stmt2 = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM stages limit 1");
while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()) {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
    $s1="UPDATE task SET name_t='".$_POST['name_t']."', desc_t='".$_POST['desc_t']."', process_t='".$_POST['process_t']."', status_t='".$row2['status_t']."', client_t='".$_POST['user_id']."'  WHERE id_t='".$_POST['id']."'";
}
}
}
$pdo->exec($s1);
header("Location: /taskedit/?done&id=".$_POST['id']."");
?>
```

Такие ошибки:
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id in * on line 11

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in * on line 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что вы пытаетесь сделать

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM task WHERE id_t = ".$_GET['id']."");
```

вот что вы получаете

> PHP Notice: Undefined index: id in * on line 11

В переводе на русский, вам сказано, что в `_GET` нет поля `id`. параметр не передан.

Что получаете в тексте запроса, если параметра нет? Вот что

```
SELECT * FROM task WHERE id_t =
```

Валидный ли этот запрос? нет. очевидна синтаксическая ошибка. Что возращает метод `query` ? в данном случае? Возвращает `false`.

Что вы далее делаете?

```
$row = $stmt->fetch()
```

у `false` есть метод `fetch` ? Нет. Что вам пхп отвечает на это?

> PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in * on line 12

В переводе - невозможно вызвать метод `fetch` у булевой переменной.

Что надо в этой ситуации сделать?

- Убедиться что параметра `$_GET['id']` передан скрипту.
- Если не передан, то выстроить логику скрипта иначе
- передать значение параметра в запрос, используя [подготовленные выражения c `prepare` и `execute`](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php)